# Joint Trajectory Controller with velocity command interface has non-zero velocity after finshed trajectory

Tags: joint-trajectory-controller, ros2-controllers

I want to control a manipulator with the [Joint Trajectory Controller](https://control.ros.org/humble/doc/ros2_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/doc/userdoc.html) by using the **velocity command interface**. I am planning a trajectory with with MoveIt `MotionPlanning`of rviz. I am using ros2 humble.

I've tested several setups but with all of them I have the same problem: When the Joint Trajectory Controller reports "Goal reached, success!", **the velocities aren't set to zero**. I tried to play with with the parameters (increasing and decreasing `stopped_velocity_tolerance` or `goal_time`, changing the `gains`, adding and removing `ff_velocity_scale`) which sometimes leads to a smaller final velocity but never to completely stopped motion.

A simple setup to reproduce this issue is by launching `ros2 launch moveit2_tutorials demo.launch.py` from (moveit2_tutorials)[https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2_tutorials] but with changing from position to velocity interface in the `panda_moveit_config`. I changed

1. Settings for `panda_arm_controller` in `ros2_controllers.yaml` to:

```
panda_arm_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    command_interfaces:
      - velocity
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
    joints:
      - panda_joint1
      - panda_joint2
      - panda_joint3
      - panda_joint4
      - panda_joint5
      - panda_joint6
      - panda_joint7
    gains:
      panda_joint1:
        p: 10.0
        i: 1.0
        d: 1.0
        i_clamp: 1.0
        ff_velocity_scale: 1.0
      panda_joint2:
        p: 10.0
        i: 1.0
        d: 1.0
        i_clamp: 1.0
        ff_velocity_scale: 1.0
      panda_joint3:
        p: 10.0
        i: 1.0
        d: 1.0
        i_clamp: 1.0
        ff_velocity_scale: 1.0
      panda_joint4:
        p: 10.0
        i: 1.0
        d: 1.0
        i_clamp: 1.0
        ff_velocity_scale: 1.0
      panda_joint5:
        p: 10.0
        i: 1.0
        d: 1.0
        i_clamp: 1.0
        ff_velocity_scale: 1.0
      panda_joint6:
        p: 10.0
        i: 1.0
        d: 1.0
        i_clamp: 1.0
        ff_velocity_scale: 1.0
      panda_joint7:
        p: 10.0
        i: 1.0
        d: 1.0
        i_clamp: 1.0
        ff_velocity_scale: 1.0
```

2. Setting command_interface from **position** to **velocity** in `panda.ros2_control.xacro`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <xacro:macro name="panda_ros2_control" params="name initial_positions_file ros2_control_hardware_type">
        <xacro:property name="initial_positions" value="${xacro.load_yaml(initial_positions_file)['initial_positions']}"/>

        <ros2_control name="${name}" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <xacro:if value="${ros2_control_hardware_type == 'mock_components'}">
                    <plugin>mock_components/GenericSystem</plugin>
                    <param name="calculate_dynamics">true</param>
                </xacro:if>
                <xacro:if value="${ros2_control_hardware_type == 'isaac'}">
                <plugin>topic_based_ros2_control/TopicBasedSystem</plugin>
                <param name="joint_commands_topic">/isaac_joint_commands</param>
                <param name="joint_states_topic">/isaac_joint_states</param>
            </xacro:if>
        </hardware>
        <joint name="panda_joint1">
            <command_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
              <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint1']}</param>
                </state_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="panda_joint2">
                <command_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position">
                  <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint2']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="panda_joint3">
            <command_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
              <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint3']}</param>
                </state_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="panda_joint4">
                <command_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position">
                  <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint4']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="panda_joint5">
            <command_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
              <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint5']}</param>
                </state_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="panda_joint6">
                <command_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position">
                  <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint6']}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="panda_joint7">
            <command_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
              <param name="initial_value">${initial_positions['panda_joint7']}</param>
                </state_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            </joint>
        </ros2_control>
    </xacro:macro>
</robot>
```

Now you can run `ros2 launch moveit2_tutorials demo.launch.py`, open a second terminal and run `ros2 topic echo /joint_states`. Plan an arbitrary trajectory by using rviz and hit `Plan & Execute` in the `MotionPlanning` panel of rviz. Then you should see a motion being executed and the terminal should report:

```
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1697458106.110702550] [panda_arm_controller]: Goal reached, success!
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1697458106.122919526] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Controller 'panda_arm_controller' successfully finished
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1697458106.151076866] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Completed trajectory execution with status SUCCEEDED ...
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1697458106.151414260] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Solution was found and executed.
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1697458106.151859534] [move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request complete!
```

In parallel you can check the logs of `ros2 topic echo /joint_states` which should report **non-zero velocities even after the trajectory is successfully executed**. Therefore the arm keeps moving (slowly but steady) and you should see the positions constantly changing.

Is this the intended behavior of the Joint Trajectory Controller? Or do I just have a bad parameter setup? Any help or hint on what the problem could be would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which ROS distro are you using? This is a well-known "feature"/bug and was [fixed for rolling/iron packages](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/pull/558). I plan to backport this fix to humble, but this might still take some time to ensure not breaking existing setups.